# Make aurelia-ui-virtualization work with tables

Tags: aurelia

I'm struggling to make Aurelia `virtual-repeat.for` work with `table` and `tr` elements. Here is my markup of the modified Users page of [aurelia skeleton app](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation):

```
<table style="width:500px; height: 200px; overflow-y:scroll; display:block">
  <tr virtual-repeat.for="user of users" style="width:500px; height: 50px">
    <td>
      ${user.avatar_url}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I scroll the table down, the items below aren't rendered and I see just the empty space all over. What am I missing?

Comment: There seems to be a bug with calculating the height table rows in UI-Virtualization. Does it work if you remove height: 50px? Can you please create an issue for this and I will take a look: http://github.com/aurelia/ui-virtualization/issues/new

Comment: @Gusten Created an issue https://github.com/aurelia/ui-virtualization/issues/43 . Removing "height: 50px" for tr seems to fix virtualization indeed, although I think it did not help when I tried with my original application...

Comment: This saved me a ton of work! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed in version 0.4.3, so the described scenario is working now